# About repairing permissions in the mac mini

Tags: macos, mac, permission

If one uses several different programs including the mac disk utility to repair permissions on the computer maybe 3 or 4 times in one day can this 'hurt' the computer or can one use these utility programs many times with impunity?

Comment: It shouldn't hurt but the bigger question is why one might be doing this so many times in a day? It really should not need to be done often, if at all. I think I've had to do it once in the 9 years I've been using modern-era Macs.

Comment: Do they call it benchmarking when the limits of a program and the computer are tested? Have repairing- permission programs been 'benchmark tested'?

Comment: Still the question is 'why do you think this may be necessary?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run "Repair Permissions" as often as you want. All it does is accessing a lot of files/folders and comparing their permissions to a master list known to the OS. In theory this puts a bit more wear and tear on the hard drive (assuming no SSD), but in practice you will get bored of rerunning "Repair Permissions" every few minutes before any negative effects show up (unless the drive was defective already anyway).

OTOH, if you *need* to run "Repair Permissions" every few hours because permissions get changed so often, you might have a problem worth looking into.

Comment: @201044 if this is helpful: up vote it. Don't comment that it's helpful. The way we say "thank you" here is with an up vote. For more information on how Ask Different and the StackExchange Q&A format works please see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).